# A clean way to wipe out mapbox FeatureCollections without losing layers and sources?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am initializing mapbox map by adding sources and layers linked to them.

```
    mapbox.addSource(MY_SOURCE, {
        'type': 'geojson',
        'data': {
            'type': 'FeatureCollection',
            'features': [],
        },
    });

    mapbox.addLayer({
        'id': MY_LAYER,
        'type': 'circle',
        'source': MY_SOURCE,
        'paint': {
            'circle-radius': 6,
            'circle-color': '#d31467',
        },
    });
```

my goal being - I want to have those definitions done once and then - if I need to update the source I just:

```
    mapbox.getSource(MY_SOURCE).setData(geojson);
```

Sometimes though I need to wipe out all polygons, all points, everything. How can I do that without losing all those definitions? I can only see [`.removeSource`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#removesource), [`.removeLayer`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#removelayer) - which tells me I will actually need to recreate those definitions.

Is there a less destructive way of doing it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two options here:

1. Hide the layers

   ```
   map.setLayoutProperty(<layer-id>, 'visibility', 'none');
   ```
2. Remove all features from you sources by setting an empty geojson

   ```
   map.getSource(<source-id>).setData({
     type: 'FeatureCollection',
     features: []  // <--- no features
   });
   ```

Also removing & re-adding the sources and layers might not be the worst option, depending on the frequency you want to do this.

Comment: Yes, you are right. That's what I started to think after I posted my question - basically, it should not be too frequent, so recreating sources should not be an issue.